# How to pivot table in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table illustrated on the attached screen:

[image]

And data is presented:

[image]

As you can see it contains all fields from lines (value, column_id - is field type). Each field has `line_index` and `column_index` of position and `column_id`.

I want to get back all lines with all field names like:

```
line_index column_id_1  column_name1 column_id_2   column_name2   column_id_3   column_name3  
0          1             Age           2            Vasile         3              NY
```

More simply I need to build all fields(rows) to columns then to lines back.

Should I use Pivot and is it possible in MySQL?

Link to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0dfa73/1/0)

Comment: Anywords for each line_index I need to get all column_name with value

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0dfa73/3

Comment: May be aI am wrong in design table?

Comment: Where will you show the pivot table? If its on a web page, you can look at JavaScript libraries such as pivottable.js which is quite simple to use. Take a look at https://pivottable.js.org/examples/

Comment: @Sudhir This isn't really a scalable idea. The data might be simply too large for it to handle sometimes, and in most cases a RDBMS would provide better performance.

Comment: Could you explain more. I did not get, you mean SQL is not suitable for that?

Comment: I meant using a javascript library, something which could possibly be executed on the clients machine isn't a good idea for performing operations which could be done by a RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to group the results by `line_index` and conditionally transform rows to columns.

```
SELECT l.line_index, 
MAX(CASE WHEN ct.column_name = "NAME" THEN l.value ELSE NULL END) AS "NAME" ,
MAX(CASE WHEN ct.column_name = "AGE" THEN l.value ELSE NULL END) AS "AGE" ,
MAX(CASE WHEN ct.column_name = "ZUP" THEN l.value ELSE NULL END) AS "ZUP" 
FROM columns_types ct 
LEFT JOIN `lines` l ON l.column_id = ct.column_id
GROUP BY l.line_index;
```

[Try it here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s1U2TNGVrmMqaH6WfjZyG3/0). Also I did some changes in your schema which I felt didn't impact the data stored in the tables. You were adding redundant rows(perhaps) in your `columns_types` table. And by looking at the query, you know that you will have to build a `MAX(CASE` statement for each column, so its best if you first fetch it and then build the final query in some programming language.

Comment: Thank you it that I need, but I can not use static columns name in SELECT, it is stored in another table. So maybe I am wrong in db design?

Comment: You got most of the part right. If you look carefully in my fiddle, I did remove some redundant entries in your schema. And as you rightly said that column names are not static, is the reason why I said that if you have a script interacting with the RDBMS, its much easier to do so by using a select query and then running a loop to build the actual query.